# Проблема сохранения в String в SharedPreferences через цикл for

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Имеется очень много полей EditText, которые для рациональности я поместил в массив. Также у меня есть столько же строк, в которые должен считываться введенный в editText текст. Раньше я обращался к каждому элементу отдельно, то есть в отдельных строках прописывал

```
ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, editText1.getText().toString());
ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT2, editText2.getText().toString());
```

Но это занимает слишком много места и обращаться вот так вот отдельно к 16 элементам неправильно. Однако при попытке считать текст из каждого элемента в соответствующую строку по очереди через цикл, у меня возникает проблема - текст считывается только из последней строки. В чем ошибка моего цикла?

Неполный код, только основное:

```
EditText[] editTexts;

final String[] SAVED_TEXTS = {
        "saved_text",
        "saved_text2",
        "saved_text3",
        "saved_text4",
        "saved_text5",
        "saved_text6",
        "saved_text7",
        "saved_text8"};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pnday);

    editTexts = new EditText[]{
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7),
            (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText8)};
}

void saveText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    for (final EditText editText : editTexts) {
        for (final String SAVED_TEXT : SAVED_TEXTS) {
            ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, editText.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    ed.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Двойный цикл означает, что значение каждого `editText` по очереди подставляется в `ed` с каждым `SAVED_TEXT`. Как результат - в `ed` значения перезатираются и в итоге все значения из последнего `editText`

Для реализации "для каждого `SAVED_TEXT` значение из соответствующего (по индексу) `editText`" подойдёт одиночный цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < editTexts.length; i++)
{
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXTS[i], editTexts[i].getText().toString());
}
```

---

Код на компиляцию не проверял, но идея должна быть понятна